# Entire Python list not getting written into CSV file

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list as output from a program which contains multiple lists inside it. I'm trying to write it into a CSV file, but only the fist part is getting written. 
The list is:

```
"['DELETE', 'FROM', 'abc', 'WHERE', ['c', '=', 'book']]\n- from: [['abc']]\n  [0]:\n    ['abc']\n- table: [['abc']]\n  [0]:\n    ['abc']\n- where_expr: ['c', '=', 'book']"
```

I converted the list to dictionary as follows:

```
   dict1={'delete': delete_list}
   df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=[0])
```

My output is:

```
         delete
0         ['DELETE', 'FROM', 'abc', 'WHERE', ['c', '=', 'book']]
```

I read some similar question and tried this..The entire output is written in the dataframe but I'm getting a single character in every row.

```
df2=pd.DataFrame([i for i in delete_list],columns=['Query'])
df2
```

Output is:

```
      Query
   0    [
   1    '
   2    D
   3    E
   4    L
   5    E
   6    T

   .
   .
```

it goes on....

What I'm actually trying is to have a different column for every nested list.
Like 1st column will have the *first list* then 2nd column will have the list from: `[['abc']]\n  [0]:\n ['abc']` 3rd will have table: `[['abc']]` and so on..
Also how do I get rid of \n?? strip() is not working!

Comment: What is `\n- from: [['abc']]` supposed to mean?

Comment: This is the result I get after parsing a sql delete query using PyParsing. I parsed the query so that it results in showing the relations of each keyword. \n and - are created by itself. from is the keyword and the action is done on abc.. The query goes like : **delete from abc where c=book**

Comment: I just glanced at the github page for PyParsing. It looks like it's supposed to return a list, I don't know why you're getting a string like this.

Comment: That list cannot be used further so I had to change it. I tried removing : and - and now it says unexpected indent. I don't think it's a problem for list conversion.

Comment: You need to solve the problem of getting a proper list structure out of PyParsing. You can't do anything useful with this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to write to a CSV file, you don't need `pandas`, simply use the `csv` module (in the standard library):

```
import csv
with open('dump.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([delete_list])
```

or perhaps

```
import csv
with open('dump.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(delete_list.split("\n"))
```

Comment: `delete_list` isn't a list, so `writerow(delete_list)` won't work.

Comment: Thanks! Though it is not a list , It is almost what I wanted. I changed the lineterminator to `lineterminator=' -'` and `delimiter= ,`